# Using sublime to edit R installed on a linux server

Tags: linux, r, sublimetext2

I am on a windows machine using sublime text 2. I have installed R on my separate Cent Os box on my network. I have Sshfs manager I use to mount the R box's hard drive on my windows. I use that because it seemed easier to open the project by just adding it as a folder in sublime since I have that mounted as a hard drive.

I've installed sublimeREPL. When I try to configure it, I am having hard time correctly adjusting the default_extend_env variable.

My R is on a separate linux box on my network. 
My sublime is on a windows machine that is on the same network as the R box.

What is my sublimeREPL default_extend_env value ?

I used "PATH": "{PATH}:/usr/local/bin" and been altering with it but no luck - assuming because it is on a different linux box.

Thanks